# How do I disable the touchpad on my Macbook pro

Tags: macbook, touchpad

The touchpad on my Macbook Pro is acting up so I wanted to be able to disable it completely while using a bluetooth mouse. Any way to disable trackpad?

Comment: Hope that helped, you didn't specify your OS.

Answer (score 1):

OS X v10.7 Lion or OS X Mountain Lion v10.8

1.From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.

2.From the View menu, choose Accessibility.

3.Click the Mouse & Trackpad pane.

OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard

1.From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.

2.From the View menu, choose Universal Access.

3.Click the Mouse & Trackpad pane.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3608